# Android Studio: Right clicking and running a test always defaults to a Gradle configuration

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

*Using Android Studio 3.2*

[image]

Whenever I try to run a specific test for a class or method (either from right clicking the file -> Run or using the green triangle run button in the editor "gutter") Android Studio automatically creates a build configuration and attempts to run the test.

[image]

This auto-created build configuration is always a Gradle one opposed to an "Android JUnit" or "Android Instrumented Tests" configuration. I have to always manually create a build configuration if I want to run a specific test class or test method.

How do I change this? It's driving me crazy.

---

Update - build.gradle and extra info:

```
// app/build.gradle

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.kotlincoroutines"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I just opened this same project on another computer (thus different Android Studio config), and it's defaulting to the right build configuration.

Comment: Can you share your app level build.gradle file?